# How do I get Visual Studio to compile my application with OpenCV support?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, linker, unresolved-external

I need to compie and run a windows program that uses `OpenCV`. For that, I've downloaded and installed `MS Visual Studio 2010`. I confirmed that I can compile & run a Hello World terminal application.

Now, I've installed `OpenCV` and set up the Compiler and Linker paths accordingly. I wrote a little sample application:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<iostream>

using namespace cv;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Mat img = imread("7MLS142.jpg");
    namedWindow("image", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("image", img);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

but get the following errors when I want to compile and run it:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Hello_World, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 2018-12-11 11:42:00 AM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\Hello_World.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>  Hello_World.cpp
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>Hello_World.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cv::waitKey(int)" (?waitKey@cv@@YAHH@Z) referenced in function _wmain
1>Hello_World.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::imshow(class cv::String const &,class cv::debug_build_guard::_InputArray const &)" (?imshow@cv@@YAXABVString@1@ABV_InputArray@debug_build_guard@1@@Z) referenced in function _wmain
1>Hello_World.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::namedWindow(class cv::String const &,int)" (?namedWindow@cv@@YAXABVString@1@H@Z) referenced in function _wmain
1>Hello_World.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::Mat __cdecl cv::imread(class cv::String const &,int)" (?imread@cv@@YA?AVMat@1@ABVString@1@H@Z) referenced in function _wmain
1>Hello_World.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: char * __thiscall cv::String::allocate(unsigned int)" (?allocate@String@cv@@AAEPADI@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall cv::String::String(char const *)" (??0String@cv@@QAE@PBD@Z)
1>Hello_World.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __thiscall cv::String::deallocate(void)" (?deallocate@String@cv@@AAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall cv::String::~String(void)" (??1String@cv@@QAE@XZ)
1>Hello_World.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::fastFree(void *)" (?fastFree@cv@@YAXPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall cv::Mat::~Mat(void)" (??1Mat@cv@@QAE@XZ)
1>Hello_World.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::deallocate(void)" (?deallocate@Mat@cv@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::release(void)" (?release@Mat@cv@@QAEXXZ)
1>c:\users\rideo\src\visual studio 2010\Projects\Hello_World\Debug\Hello_World.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:03.46
```

The `Additional library path` in the `Linker` setting is set to `%OPENCV_DIR%\bin` where I have set `setx -m OPENCV_DIR  C:\Users\rideo\opencv\build\x64\vc14` (There's a `vc14` & a `vc15`) directory and I have installed 'Visual Studio 2010` - is that what's causing the problem here?

**UPDATE**

I've now installed `MS Visual Studio Professional 2015`, set C:\Users\rideo\opencv\build\x64\vc15`, opened the same  project but still get:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Hello_World, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 2018-12-11 2:09:41 PM.
1>     1>
1>_PrepareForClean:
1>         Deleting file "Debug\Hello_World.tlog\Hello_World.lastbuildstate".
1>       InitializeBuildStatus:
1>         Touching "Debug\Hello_World.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
1>       ClCompile:
1>         stdafx.cpp
1>         Hello_World.cpp
1>     1>
1>Hello_World.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::fastFree(void *)" (?fastFree@cv@@YAXPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall cv::Mat::~Mat(void)" (??1Mat@cv@@QAE@XZ)
1>     1>
1>Hello_World.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: char * __thiscall cv::String::allocate(unsigned int)" (?allocate@String@cv@@AAEPADI@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall cv::String::String(char const *)" (??0String@cv@@QAE@PBD@Z)
1>     1>
1>Hello_World.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: void __thiscall cv::String::deallocate(void)" (?deallocate@String@cv@@AAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall cv::String::~String(void)" (??1String@cv@@QAE@XZ)
1>     1>
1>Hello_World.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::deallocate(void)" (?deallocate@Mat@cv@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall cv::Mat::release(void)" (?release@Mat@cv@@QAEXXZ)
1>     1>
1>Hello_World.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::Mat __cdecl cv::imread(class cv::String const &,int)" (?imread@cv@@YA?AVMat@1@ABVString@1@H@Z) referenced in function _wmain
1>     1>
1>Hello_World.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::namedWindow(class cv::String const &,int)" (?namedWindow@cv@@YAXABVString@1@H@Z) referenced in function _wmain
1>     1>
1>Hello_World.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cv::waitKey(int)" (?waitKey@cv@@YAHH@Z) referenced in function _wmain
1>     1>
1>Hello_World.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::imshow(class cv::String const &,class cv::debug_build_guard::_InputArray const &)" (?imshow@cv@@YAXABVString@1@ABV_InputArray@debug_build_guard@1@@Z) referenced in function _wmain
1>     1>
1>C:\Users\rideo\src\visual studio 2010\Projects\Hello_World\Debug\Hello_World.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.92
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

This is with `opencv-3.4.3-vc14_vc15.exe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vc14` is for the builds using `Visual studio 2015`.

But you have installed Visual studio 2010

For VS2010, the environment variable should be set using (depends on 32 bit or 64 bit)

```
setx -m OPENCV_DIR D:\OpenCV\Build\x86\vc10     (suggested for Visual Studio 2010 - 32 bit Windows)
setx -m OPENCV_DIR D:\OpenCV\Build\x64\vc10     (suggested for Visual Studio 2010 - 64 bit Windows)
```

Here is more guidance for using static or dynamic libraries:

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windowssetpathandenviromentvariable

And here is the detailed guide with screenshots, regarding all the required project settings that are required to use OpenCV in visual studio 2015 C++ projects.

https://www.opencv-srf.com/2017/11/install-opencv-with-visual-studio.html

Comment: There's no `vc10` directory

Comment: which version of openCV you are installing? you many need to go with lower version (2.4) if you have to use visual studio 2010. Else install visual studio 2015

Comment: @cerr Could you please walkthrough this link and check you did every step https://www.opencv-srf.com/2017/11/install-opencv-with-visual-studio.html

Comment: Thank you sir! That guide helped me! You can transfer this to an answer and I'll gladly accept it!

Comment: @cerr good to hear that. Added the link to answer, so that it will be useful for some more people, who need it.